# Searching for a lock-free possibility to swap two associative containers

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to implement the feature toggle pattern. To do that, I load the contents of a configuration file containing the feature toggles into a map. After that, there is a function where you can check whether a feature toggle is set or not. Now, parts of our development want a function to re-initialize the map so that they can change the toggle while the application is running (edit the file, call re-initialize).

Since the toggle mechanism should be fast, I'd like to implement the fastest possible way to read the toggles. Re-initializing the map can be slow - that is no problem. Reading without writing would be thread-safe, but with the re-initialize function, I need to care about threading issues.

My current solution uses reader locks in the read function and exclusive locks in the write function. But my goal would be to live without locks in the read functions. Any ideas?

Regards
Tobias

Comment: How about the intrinsic operations? Not exactly a lock but ensures you can read the value without it being changed at the same time.

Comment: but where - I have a complex data structure where you simply can't do a single intrinsic operation. One option I see is to work with a memory leak on purpose when re-initializing. But I'd like to avoid the leak.

Comment: It's a difficult question to answer without knowing the types involved. If it were a simple task of reading an int here or a boolean there then intinsics are the best option. For sth more complicated... How about keeping two copies of the map? one for writing, and at certain intervals flush the changes to the copy? Still requires a lock but you can limit the time.

Comment: as I said - it's the feature toggle pattern as presented by Mr. Fowler (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html). So you need a associative container that resolves a string into a bool. But still, it's a container containing multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only unsafe operations should be those that modify the structure of the tree.  Simply updating the value in a node is safe.  Therefore, when "re-initializing", simply visit each node in the "old" tree, and if the new configuration has no setting, either leave it untouched or change the value to an "unknown" state.  If the new configuration has a setting for a node in the existing tree, simply update it and move on.

If you really, really need to be able to add new feature toggles on the fly (why?), you could make a second data structure which is just a dumb, flat list of "added" features, and only ever append there.  Then, when a reader queries for a feature, look in the tree first (fast), and then if needed in the list (slow, but uncommon).

Finally, you could do something like "z buffering" where you keep two complete trees and a pointer to the "active" one.  You only update the "inactive" one and then flip the pointer to make it active.  This might require a simple reference counting operation when readers are using the active tree (so you don't update a second time while some readers exist on the old-old tree), but that should be inexpensive.

Comment: the problem here is, if someone adds new nodes to the tree. Std::map may rebalance and then I'll run into problems. But the idea with the flipping might work since I could lock the re-initialize and guarantee that there's no-one working on the in-active at the same time. The only problem that I see here is if re-initialize is called a second time shortly after the first time. Then there might be still some reader in the now inactive tree while it is cleared/re-initialized.

Comment: Yes I agree with all those concerns.  I think I explored them already in my answer.  Please read it over carefully and hopefully you will see that I have suggested those issues can either be safely ignored, mitigated, or resolved.

Comment: Regarding the use case of adding new feature toggles - we work together with an "interactive" development environment like smalltalk. They don't want to shut down their IDE for introducing new toggles. They can change code on the fly.